# Finding coordinates of ground-zero with seismic sensors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

At the unknown `t0` time an explosion occurred at an unknown point `X,Y` on the `2D` plane.

We have several seismic sensors at points `X1,Y1`, `X2,Y2`, ..., `Xn,Yn` - they register explosion at moments `t1`, `t2`, ... , `tn`.

Suppose that seismic wave propagates with unknown but **constant** speed `V`.

How can we then find out `X,Y` of the explosion?

I faced such problem about 6 years ago and solved it somehow (I believe it was iterative solution). Recently I added it to my programming-puzzles site (http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/ground-zero) but later I was asked by several users how this problem could be solved precisely (i.e. analytically) - and I still do not know this.

**My idea of solution** was like the following:

We have `4` variables and `4` or more binding equations for them. Regretfully, the system is not linear.

Nevertheless, if we fix `V` to some constant, we have only `3` variables left and can solve any three of equations for them.

We can choose these three equations in several ways (e.g. we can make `4` triplets out of `4` equations) - so we can find solution for each triplet and then calculate some aggregated "difference" of these solutions (like area of minimum polygon to enclose all solutions for `X,Y`).

So we now may search through values of `V` with the goal to minimize this "difference" of solutions.

It works (as other iterative approaches also do). But this give not a clue for precise **geometric / analytical** solution.

Answer (score 0):

if the explosion goes outward in a circular radius that increases at a constant speed, could you not, convert to polar and then use the X and Y to determine how much the radius increased? For instance, let's suppose your explosion happened at 0,0 and at 2 seconds your trigger was at (3,4) -- 5 meters away.

Then, if another explosion happened at 10 meters way, within 4 seconds total, and a third explosion happened at equivalent radius of 15 meters within 6 seconds total, this is constant and you can tell the V was 2.5 meters per second.

On the other hand, if the difference between the 15 and 10 vs 10 and 5 was off, you know that (0,0) is not the coordinate of the explosion. By assuming your explosion is at a certain spot, you can change your idea to (x3-x2)/t = (x2-x1)/t = (x1-x0)/t, where x3, x2 and x1 are known  radius and x0 is the unknown X coordinate.

Does this seem logical?